# Scroll to DIV with in the Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 buttons that will trigger same modal but need to scroll to different sections. I am struggling to achieve this, kindly help.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-goto-section-1"> Launch modal </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-goto-section-2"> Launch modal </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn-goto-section-3"> Launch modal </a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="section-1">
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
        </div>
        <div id="section-2">
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
        </div>
        <div id="section-3">
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you will have to add the scroll code to the Bootstrap's modal open callback.

Comment: you need scrolling inside modal or for whole page, because if need inside modal then modal should have fixed height

Comment: @Virendrayadav the modal will be filled by dynamic content and can't have fixed height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261016/scroll-to-element-inside-modal-window

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the modal event `shown.bs.modal` and use `data` for the section. The link which opened the modal can be found at `event.relatedTarget`.

Here you go:-

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
  // reset the scroll to top
  $('#myModal .modal-body').scrollTop(0);
  // get the section using data
  var section = $(event.relatedTarget).data('section');
  // get the top of the section
  var sectionOffset = $('#' + section).offset();
  //scroll the container
  $('#myModal .modal-body').animate({
    scrollTop: sectionOffset.top - 30
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  height: 300px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.modal-body {
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-section="section-1"> Launch modal </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-section="section-2"> Launch modal </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-section="section-3"> Launch modal </a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="sdfsd" class="modal-body">
        <div id="section-1">
          <h1>section-1</h1>
          <div class="red"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="section-2">
          <h1>section-2</h1>
          <div class="green"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="section-3">
          <h1>section-3</h1>
          <div class="blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As **@Virendra yadav** comment, if the modal has a dynamic height and you want to scroll the body, and not a div within the modal, then replace:-

```
// get the top of the section
var sectionOffset = $('#' + section).offset();
//scroll the container
$('#myModal .modal-body').animate({
   scrollTop: sectionOffset.top - 30
}, "slow");
```

with

```
// get the div position
var position = $('#' + section).position();
// scroll modal to position top
$("#myModal").scrollTop(position.top);
```

Comment: BG101 you are right but he does not want to fix height of modal so animate can work on document  see my example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdLZPx

Comment: I didn't see the comment about dynamic content, added your suggestion.

Comment: @BG101 sorry for ME being so dumb :) I still cannot make it work for dynamic height of the modal. I am not able to understand your solutions with mix and match with dynamic height solution you gave.

Comment: @BG101 I just removed `.modal-body` and things stared working. Thanks. @Virendrayadav thanks for your solution, even that too worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea. Make the modal scroll once it is shown (`shown.bs.modal`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) { 
      $target = $('#section-3');
      $('.modal-body').animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top + 'px'
      }, 'fast');

    });
});
```

JS BIN: http://jsbin.com/hagida/3/edit?html,js,output